# SQL insert in php not working

Tags: php

Im very new to php and trying to get a register up and working , my code at the minute is only loading the username into the database and nothing else. Although it does enter values into other fields of the database if I hard-code them into sql insert and dont use

```
$users_Password
```

etc. btw I know this is terrible code and passwords should be hashed etc but ive literally just tore this code apart because this wont work and will add everything back in after this is sorted out cheers , this is my code

form

```
<form id = "Register_form" action="Register.php" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="Username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
            Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword"><br>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
            Surname: <input type="text" name="Surname"><br>
            Address Line 1: <input type="text" name="AddressLine1"><br>
            Address Line 2: <input type="text" name="AddressLine2"><br>
            City: <input type="text" name="City"><br>
            Telephone: <input type="text" name="Telephone"><br>
            Mobile: <input type="text" name="Mobile"><br></br>
            <input type="submit">
```

then in the Register.php file

```
<?php
                // create connection
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","book");  
                // check connection
                if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
                    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }

                $users_Username = $_POST['Username'];
                $users_Password = $_POST['Password'];
                $users_ConfirmPassword = $_POST['ConfirmPassword'];
                $users_FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
                $users_Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
                $users_AddressLine1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
                $users_AddressLine2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
                $users_City = $_POST['City'];
                $users_Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
                $users_Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];
                //Multiple Error checkings such as 
                if ($users_Username == "")
                {
                    echo "Please enter a username";
                    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
                }
                else if ($users_Password = "")
                {
                    echo "Please enter a password";
                    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
                }
                else if ($users_ConfirmPassword == $users_Password)
                {
                    if (strlen($users_Password)<=6)
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$users_Username', '$users_Password', '$users_FirstName', '$users_Surname','$users_AddressLine1','$users_AddressLine2','$users_City','$users_Telephone','$users_Mobile')";

                        if($con->query($sql) === TRUE)
                        {
                            echo "User succesfully registered";
                            echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Log_In_Screen.php';\",1500);</script>";


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Unable to register user, Please try again";
                            echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
                        }

                        //echo "<pre>\n$sql\n</pre>\n";
                        mysql_query($sql);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "The password you entered is too long, max characters is 6";
                        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Passwords do not match, Please try again";
                    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
                }

                mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
```

It seems like nothing will insert into the database except the username , any one have a way to fix this ?
Cheers

Comment: could you show us schema of your users table please? is there an id field?

Comment: Also he shouldn't use the `mysql` extension...is deprecated and obsolete...also he should use query parameters...

Comment: No protection to SQL injections... no verification if username already taken... I think here is, along the problem he asked for a solution, a lot of other things going wrong.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` probably part of your issue :/ FYI stick with `mysqli_`

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which will fix any pesky quoting issues you may be having.

Comment: MAX 6 for a PASSWORD??? What... why?

Answer (score 0):

You had stuff all over the place and were mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` not to mention you left yourself wide open for SQL injection. Using the script you had I stuck with `mysqli` used `prepared statements` and split your validation and persistence up. There are comments that will explain some of this

```
<?php
    $users_Username = $_POST['Username'];
    $users_Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $users_ConfirmPassword = $_POST['ConfirmPassword'];
    $users_FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $users_Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
    $users_AddressLine1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
    $users_AddressLine2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
    $users_City = $_POST['City'];
    $users_Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
    $users_Mobile = $_POST['Mobile'];

    //LETS JUST DO ERROR CHECKING ONLY
    $valid = true; //Used to verify that user input is as expected.
    //All the validation as before just as ifs and will set the 
    //$valid flag to false when validation fails.
    if ($users_Username == "")
    {
        $valid = false;
        echo "Please enter a username";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
    }
    if ($users_Password = "")
    {
        $valid = false;
        echo "Please enter a password";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
    }
    if (strlen($users_Password)>6)
    {
        $valid = false;
        echo "The password you entered is too long, max characters is 6";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
    }

    if ($users_ConfirmPassword != $users_Password)
    {
        $valid = false;
        echo "Passwords do not match, Please try again";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Register_Form.php';\",1500);</script>";
    }

    //Separating validation and persistence mean you only
    //open a connection and persist when needed.
    if($valid)
    {
        //NOW WE ONLY CONNECT WHEN YOU NEED TO!                
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","book");  

        // check connection
        if(!$con)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        //YOU MAY NEED TO SPECIFY THE COLUMNS YOU ENTER
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        //ASSUMING ALL 9 PARAMETERS ARE STRINGS hence the sssssssss
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssss', $users_Username,$users_Password,$users_FirstName,$users_Surname,$users_AddressLine1,$users_AddressLine2,$users_City,$users_Telephone,$users_Mobile);

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
        {
            echo "User succesfully registered";
            echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'http://localhost/webD/Assignment/Log_In_Screen.php';\",1500);</script>";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

What content lands in your database?

Try the following in the appropriate line:

```
"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('".$users_Username."', '".$users_Password."', '".$users_FirstName."', '".$users_Surname."','".$users_AddressLine1."','".$users_AddressLine2."','".$users_City."','".$users_Telephone."','".$users_Mobile."')";
```

PHP Params cant be evaluated in ' ' so you have to use string concatenation.

Comment: The string itself is in double quotes, so yes, it would be evaluated. The single quotes are within the double quoted string, and thus aren't part of the processing.